# A browser doesn't save cookies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I need show some info only first three times for every user. When this user visit the site a next time, he shouldn't see this info. I use cookies for this goal.

```
ViewBag.HelpShow = true;

if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("ecCount"))
{
  int count = 0;

  if (Int32.TryParse(this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["ecCount"].Value, out count))
  {
    if (count >= 3)
      ViewBag.HelpShow = false;
  }

  count++;
  this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies["ecCount"].Value = count.ToString();
}
else
{
  HttpCookie cCount = new HttpCookie("ecCount", "1");
  cCount.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);
  this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cCount);
}
```

But I've faced with problem. The problem is that this cookies are stored in browser until this browser is opened. If I close the browser and start it again, this cookies will be removed. So the question is that - how to do so cookies will be saved always - and after restarting the browser.

Comment: There should be an option to make them persistent.

Comment: Regardless of how you choose to do this (with cookies), you can't guarantee that the broswer will keep it even if marked as persistent. If for example the user chooses to delete user history in some broswers, that means the cookies might be removed as well.

Comment: @leppie MSDN tells me that I should set Expires property and I've set this. But it doesn't help me. I can't understand why

Comment: @DonTomato: My bad sorry, I thought I recalled a seperate property for that, but it seems Expires is enough.